# How can I scrape ajax site products with Python urllib & bs4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to use urllib + bs4 to scrape naturebox's website.

I want to create a voting webapp so my office can vote for new snacks from naturebox each month.

Ideally I'd like to pull the snacks from naturebox's website as they change frequently.

Here's my code:

```
 import urllib2,cookielib

site = 'http://www.naturebox.com/browse/'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)

try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print e.fp.read()

content = page.read()
print content
```

but the output is just javascript and none of the data for the actual snacks (picture, name, description, etc.)

Obviously I'm a noob - how can I get at this data?

Comment: It seems the website will give your code a template file and it use ajax to load the pic, so you can not use a common scraper to do that, try to use selenium to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Selenium Webdriver. This will allow you to load the site, including the javascript/ajax, and access the html from there. Also, try using PhantomJS so that it can run invisibly in the background.

Comment: Additionally, you could use PhearJS (https://github.com/Tomtomgo/phearjs). It wraps PhantomJS and provides a simple API to it.